# How many valence electrons does a copper atom have?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, atoms

The valence electron configuration of $\ce{Cu}$ is $\ce{4s^1 3d^{10}}$. According to this the answer is $11$, but shouldn't it be $1$ since the d shell is already filled up?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, copper only has 1 valence electron. Remember: valence electrons only include the electrons in the highest energy (n) shell.

Comment: How does it form Cu(II) then?